# Close InfoWindow for local business marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a new google map app using v3 of the API.  On it I have a few custom markers with info windows.  I use a global variable to ensure only one info window opens at any one time - everything is as it should be.

However the map comes with many local business markers, just like the ones all over this map (http://goo.gl/maps/M6m3), all of which open their own  infowindows.  If I click on one of these my infowindow doesn't get closed, and if I click on one of my markers, the built in infowindow also doesn't close - leaving multiple windows open.

Can this be resolved?

Comment: So is there a separate variable for the InfoWindows appearing over the "many local business markers"? Do you just want one InfoWindow for the whole map? How do these other markers appear? It's hard for me to understand without relevant code or a demo.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I've added a link to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want the "Points of Interest" (AKA POI) on the map to not be clickable (or to be able to capture the click on them).

This was tracked as an [FR  in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3866)  and was recently [implemented using a  new property `clickableIcons` in `MapOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapOptions)

If you set it to false, POI features will no longer be clickable. You can also use the `get/setClickableIcons` methods on the `Map` object to change this dynamically.

One other way to deal with them is to remove POIs from the map (using styled maps), if you don't want to have the infowindow open when they are clicked.

[Here (How to remove certain places on a map )](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/1962f4e70f4b23b9/3458eb9a53edf37c?lnk=gst&q=poi+remove+styledmap#3458eb9a53edf37c) is one discussion on the v3 API group about using styled maps to remove them.

And [here (Disabling POI's InfoWindows - workaround found)](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/7567cf8646c1c7d2/c037924dc0719ffc?lnk=gst&q=poi++styledmap#c037924dc0719ffc) is another.

At least now it doesn't cost more to do that [(styled maps used to be more expensive than normal maps)](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/06/lower-pricing-and-simplified-limits.html).

Comment: POI was the magic word I wasn't searching for!  Ideally I'd like these markers, and their info windows, I just want them to close when I open my own info window.  Those links seem to provide all the answers - thanks!