# Close non custom infoWindow Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple map with two custom markers with info windows.
when I one marker is clicked any opened infowindow is closed then the associated infowindow is opened with no problem.

But my client ask me to close other opened non custom info window (hotels...) before opening our custom ones.

I searched the web but nothing, if anyone has solution please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post code or a jsfiddle that shows what you are talking about? What do you mean by "non custom infoWindow"?  Is it from clicking on a POI (Point Of Interest) on the map?  If so, you can't do anything about it other than hide the POIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use styled map if you don't want to show POIs

But if you have to show it anyway, [this might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335299/close-infowindow-for-local-business-marker)