# google map. info window. disable default street view picture

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

I need to override default info window which shown for all 'default' places ( parks, museums, universities etc).

How can I disable default street view picture in info window?

All other content items are important.
I read : need to override default content of such windows , but I do not know how to do it for  'default' places.

Here is picture-example how info window look now:

[IMG]http://i42.tinypic.com/219usg7.png[/IMG]

so it should look like:

[IMG]http://i43.tinypic.com/r9n0b7.png[/IMG]

Is it imposible for 'default' places?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close InfoWindow for local business marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335299/close-infowindow-for-local-business-marker)

Comment: I tried to find a solution there, but to no avail.