# GMaps API - remove default POI

Tags: api, google-maps, maps, point-of-interest

How can I remove points of interest from google maps via API that is always rendered? I mean those points:
http://j.mp/1ktcaeB

I've seen it removed in couple of websites, but I couldn't find a way How to do it.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close InfoWindow for local business marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335299/close-infowindow-for-local-business-marker)

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
    var myStyles =[
    {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
              { visibility: "off" }
        ]
    }
];
```

Don't forget to add `styles: myStyles` to `var myOptions = {...}` also.

Take a look at the [Styled Maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?csw=1) too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the map like this:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {lat: 51, lng: 10},
    styles: [    
        {
            featureType: "poi",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are using TypeScript you will need to cast the MapTypeStyle array like this:

```
const noPoiStyle = <google.maps.MapTypeStyle[]> [
  {
    featureType: "poi",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];
```