# Google Maps API 3 - onclick urls

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google maps api inside a phonegap application.

when you click on a known google location it brings up an infowindow with details / website / urls etc. in these default infowindows i want to overide the onclick of the  elements as i want them to open in an external browser.

i have tried using jquery to find the elements but it wont bind because the html is injected dynamically. is there a map evet i can bind to or an easy way to do this ?

Cheers
Niro

Comment: You can't affect those POIs in any way, all you can do is hide them.  Related question: [Close InfoWindow for local business marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335299/close-infowindow-for-local-business-marker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) first set this

```
var set = google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.set;
    google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.set = function (key, val) {
        if (key === 'map' && ! this.get('noSuppress')) {
            //console.warn('This InfoWindow is suppressed.');
            //console.log('To enable it, set "noSuppress" option to true.');
            return;
        }
        set.apply(this, arguments);
    }
```

2) for any info windows that you open ensure you pass in the 'noSupress' parameter

```
 infowindow.set('noSuppress', true);
```